# Pandas xaxis auto-format issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

```
from pandas import *
import datetime
DataFrame([1,1], index =  [ datetime.datetime(2012,1,1), datetime.datetime(2012,9,1) ] ).plot()
```

gives a plot where the xaxis is not readable. I think the reason is that in `tools\plotting.py` the `condition` (which decides to autofmt) is false.

```
condition = (not self._use_dynamic_x
             and df.index.is_all_dates
             and not self.subplots
             or (self.subplots and self.sharex))
```

Should the first line not be `self._use_dynamic_x()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug of pandas, it should be `self._use_dynamic_x()`, please post issue to pandas, to walk around this problem:

```
import pylab as pl
from pandas import *
import datetime
df = DataFrame([1,1], index =  [ datetime.datetime(2012,1,1), datetime.datetime(2012,9,1) ] )
df.plot()
pl.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Comment: I am pretty new to the open source world so didn't realize there's an issue tracker. Thx! Posted to https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1666

Answer (score 1):

what version of pandas are you using?

I just tried it on my end and the axis looks fine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlVSg.jpg

I am on pandas 0.8.1 and matplotlib 1.1.0

Comment: Your xaxis looks slightly better than mine - see [image](http://postimage.org/image/4l3bgfz9h), but it's not slanted like if `condition` was True.

I am using 1.1.1rc2 and 0.8.0. Just upgraded to 0.8.1 but don't see a difference.

Comment: Ah I see...other than the lack of rotation, is there anything else that you feel is wrong with the labels?

Comment: No the issue is just in pandas, not in the plot per se.

Comment: Thanks for the github issue. I just put in a fix on master if you want to try it.

Comment: Thx @Chang She. Not sure if this is the right forum but I would like to contribute - what would it take for me to be able say to create a pull request just for that one line of code? I.e. how easy is it for me to cvs checkout the code, test my changes in iPython rather than with the prod version then creating a pull request? Is there a tutorial for that somewhere? I am familiar with subversion and I've done thousands of cvs commit in a proprietary system, just not familiar with the opensource tools.

Comment: We would definitely welcome any pull requests. If you check the developer page for pandas, it takes you through the whole process (http://pandas.pydata.org/developers.html).